# Monitor Traffic of virtual machines on Vmware ESXI Server

Tags: monitoring, snmp, traffic

we have some servers in traffic costing datacenters, and we offer vps services on vmware esxi, we used prtg to monitor vms by enabling snmp on server and passing their ip to PRTG. by users are able to disable snmp on their  servers and steal traffic.  is there solution to enable snmp directly on virtual NICs of vmachines ?  or any direct way to read traffic volume on vmachines?

Comment: Not tempted to use the VMware tools designed to do these jobs? vCenter and/or vRealize Business? that's what they're there for.

Comment: Perhaps do the traffic monitoring on your firewall or router using SNMP, Netflow, etc.?

Comment: v center is deployed, is there any traffic shaping feature in Vcenter?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be a bit late to the game here...  Are you still looking for a way to do this with PRTG?

If so, you could try the [VMware Virtual Machine (SOAP) sensor](https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/vmware_virtual_machine_soap_sensor), which collects info about each VM, including traffic volume, using SOAP rather than SNMP.